# SQL server 2014 installation : PerfLib 2.0 counter removal failed with exit code 13

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm trying to Install SQL Server 2014 on win server 2012 R2 and get the below error:

```
The following error has occurred:

PerfLib 2.0 counter removal failed with exit code 13. Command line: C:\Windows\system32\unlodctr.exe /m:hkengperfctr.xml from directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\.
```

Answer (score -1):

uninstall "Browser for SQL server 2017" re-run the installation app and then go through the process nothing new and then in this step :

[image: this image here]

change the startup type to AUTOMATIC and then go and finish the process the problem won't occur again .